# Aggregate result from query by quarter SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say I have a table which holds all exports for some time back in Microsoft SQL database:

```
   Name: 
   ExportTable
   Columns:
   id - numeric(18)
   exportdate - datetime
```

In order to get the number of exports per week I can run the following query:

```
SELECT  DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,[exportdate]) as 'exportdate', count(exportdate) as 'totalExports' 
FROM [ExportTable] 
Group By  DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,[exportdate]) 
order by exportdate;
```

Returns:

```
exportdate  totalExports
----------  ------------
27          13
28          12
29          15
30          8
31          17
32          10
33          7
34          15
35          4
36          18
37          10
38          14
39          14
40          21
41          19
```

Would it be possible to aggregate the week results by quarter so the output becomes something like the bellow?

**UPDATE**
Sorry for not being crystal clear, I would like the current result to add upp with previous result up to a new quarter.
Note week 41 contains 21+19 = 40
Week 39 contains 157 **(13+12+15+8+17+10+7+15+4+18+10+14+14)**

```
exportdate  totalExports    Quarter
----------  ------------    -------
27          13              3
28          25              3
29          40              3
30          48              3
31          65              3
32          75              3
33          82              3
34          97              3
35          101             3
36          119             3
37          129             3
38          143             3
39          157             3 -- Sum of 3 Quarter values.
40          21              4 -- New Quarter show current week value
41          40              4 -- (21+19)
```

Comment: You have enough reputation here that you should know we need some data to work with. As posted this is impossible to answer. Unless we just provide a literal answer to your question. "Yes it is possible".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this.

```
SELECT  
    DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,[exportdate]) as 'exportdate'
    , SUM( count(exportdate) ) OVER ( PARTITION BY DATEPART(QUARTER,MIN([exportdate])) ORDER BY DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,[exportdate]) ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) as 'totalExports'  
    , DATEPART(QUARTER,MIN([exportdate])) [Quarter]
FROM [ExportTable] 
Group By  DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,[exportdate]) 
order by exportdate;
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I want the values to be added together in the totalExports row until a new quarter appears. Is this something that is possible? Otherwise I would use this answer and fix this in the backend code.

Comment: Updated the script for the cumulative sum.

Comment: Almost correct, now it keeps adding up all rows, but for Week 40 I would like it to use the actual week 40's value since its a new quarter.

Comment: Found out this looked ugly in comment so removing it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a case statement to separate the dates into quarters.

e.g.

```
 CASE  
 WHEN EXPORT_DATE BETWEEN '1' AND '4' THEN 1   
 WHEN Export_Date BETWEEN '5' and '9' THEN 2
 ELSE 0 AS [Quarter]  
 END
```

Its just an example but you get the idea.

You could then use the alias from the case

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,[exportdate]) as 'exportdate', count(exportdate) as 'totalExports', DATEPART(quarter,[exportdate]) as quarter FROM [ExportTable] Group By  DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,[exportdate]), DATEPART(quarter,[exportdate])  order by exportdate;
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. Also, you could have at least broken your code a little bit into multiple rows, to make it readable without scrolling horizontally... Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers).